# Import headshots via CSV

Tags: extendscript, adobe-premiere

I have a sequence set up in my premiere project. It's a simple slide in from right (whilst fading in) of a headshot. Under the headshot is the name of the person (that follows the slide and fade in animation of the headshot) and I have to create a main sequence of 40 of these (each headshot sequence lasts around 3 seconds). That means manually placing the headshots (that are all the same size) and typing in the persons name for each one.

I am wondering if there is a way to automate this via a script in premiere pro that will read from a csv file the location of the headshot image and the name of the person and create it automatically for me?

I have tried looking around for such information but haven't had much success.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily acheive this using [Dataclay's Templater for Adobe After Effects](https://dataclay.com/templater).  Even better than a CSV, you can use a cloud based Google Sheet and connect directly to that asset so you never have to deal with a file again.

Comment: The question is for Adobe Premiere Pro not After Effects.